# DllIImport function throws stack exception

Tags: c#, dllimport

I trying to call the function getFirstAvailableTSSComPort in this h-file

http://sourceforge.net/p/yeicapi/code/11/tree/trunk/include/yei_threespace_api.h

Relevant structs and enums taken from h file (And converted to C# code)

```
private enum TSS_Type
{
    TSS_BTL = 0,
    TSS_USB = 1,
    TSS_DNG = 2,
    TSS_WL = 3, //wireless wired (connected to PC)
    TSS_WL_W = 4, //wireless wireless
    TSS_EM = 5,
    TSS_DL = 6,
    TSS_BT = 7,
    TSS_UNKNOWN = 8
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private struct Comport
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = 64)]
    public string Port;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public string FriendlyName;
    public TSS_Type Type;
}
```

DllImport

```
[DllImport("ThreeSpace_API.dll")]
private static extern int getFirstAvailableTSSComPort([Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] out Comport port, int filter);
```

Calling

```
Comport port;
var error = getFirstAvailableTSSComPort(out port, 0);
```

I get

> A call to PInvoke function
>   'YEi3!YEi3.Program::getFirstAvailableTSSComPort' has unbalanced the
>   stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not
>   match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling
>   convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target
>   unmanaged signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C code uses the `cdecl` calling convention, but your C# code uses `stdcall`. That is the reason why you receive the p/invoke stack imbalance message.

Change the `DllImport` to specify the calling convention:

```
[DllImport("ThreeSpace_API.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int getFirstAvailableTSSComPort(
    out Comport port, 
    int filter
);
```

Note that the default marshalling for the parameters is sufficient.

This change will resolve the stack imbalance, but your code will still fail to work. That's because the struct is translated incorrectly. The inline strings needs to be marshalled as `ByValTStr`:

```
[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct ComPort {
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=64)]
    public string com_port;
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=256)]
    public string friendly_name;
    public TSS_Type sensor_type;
}
```